# Given a coefficient vector and a value, what is the fastest way to evaluate a polynomial?

Tags: algorithm, polynomial-math

I remember reading somewhere (maybe someone can help remember where), that there is a method that is the fastest for evaluating a polynomial. Something reminds me that it had something to do with Vietta's formula, or the fact that the 0-power coefficient is the product of the 0-power coefficients of any factors of the polynomial.

I know wikipedia says it's Horner's scheme for evaluating fastest. But I recall that you actually did not have to evaluate in that way at all - it had something with the roots?

All I know for sure is that there was a method for evaluating a polynomial that has gives you a "oh that is clever" kind of feeling when you see it, but it's not too difficult and is kind of obvious.

Anyone kind or smart enough to help me out?

It is something along the lines of "you can evaluate P at x by ... " and then there is a really simple little thing that actually avoid having to do any real additions and multiplications on the order of the polynomial degree.

Comment: Maybe better suited at http://math.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: thanks. is there anyway to close the question and auto port it over? or...actually i just looked there and i'll take my chances here. with an edit to make it more appropriate....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you evaluating the polynomial more than once? Is the polynomial particularly simple? Consider the following polynomial:

```
f(a) = a^(14)
```

If we want to reduce the number of multiplications required to evaluate `f(a)` we can compute the minimal addition chain from [addition-chain exponentiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Addition-chain_exponentiation):

```
((a × a→b) × b→d) × d × d × b
```

Which shows we can compute the `f(a)` using only 5 multiplications. For a fixed polynomial with small coefficients this can be signifigant savings. Wikipeida notes:

> In practice ... shortest addition-chain exponentiation is primarily used for small fixed exponents for which a shortest chain can be precomputed and is not too large.

For many real-world cases where `f(a)` can vary another method may be appropriate, but it's worth noting alternate solutions!

Comment: Interesting. What is the → (arrow) symbol indicating? Oh I see it's a variable save. That is truly fascinating! Thank you so much for turning me on to this. Since now I am wondering : what is a fast method for finding shortest addition chains for arbitrary exponents? I thought binary method would always be the fastest. This is truly groundbreaking since it relates to something else I was thinking about....shows you how dangerous assumptions can be! I did not even wonder if there was a faster way than binary. Brilliant @Hooked!

Comment: @CrisStringfellow As far as _I_ know, there are no polynomial time solutions for finding the _shortest_ addition chain, though I know you can find approximate solutions rather quickly. The question posed is outside my realm of expertise, though I think you'd get a great answer at math.stackexchange.com If you do ask, please cross-link the questions so we can follow the answers.

Answer (score 1):

I think you looking for [Fast Fourier Transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform) it's good too see this [PowerPoint on FFT](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&ved=0CEIQFjAE&url=http://www.cs.unc.edu/~plaisted/comp750/16-fft.ppt&ei=8gXITsCOHczAtAaa6oj8Bg&usg=AFQjCNEWNXYqr9RJHJ6k0-oL2xSyBYLDag&sig2=CrC4bDfF2qEGqYCTPSKHtQ). In fact FFT is useful when you want to calculate polynomial value in n different point which is O(n log n) and very faster than Horner algorithm.

FFT works on power of n'th root of unit, and uses relation between them and because of this is very fast when you want to compute n different points value.

Comment: Emphatically, this wasn't the original method I saw, but it was very interesting, and I think it is probably the best I can get right now.

Comment: sorry, but I like the other answer better. Community please advise if changing answers is considered terribly bad practice!

Comment: @CrisStringfellow, take it easy, it's OK to accept answers which is better for your requirement.

Comment: Cool, thx! But some things you need to be careful about...such as question asking! It can be very dangerous !!! :(